# python read stored credentials in credential manager

Tags: python

```
target_name = "rtp-abs-cache.com"
credential = win32cred.CredRead(target_name, win32cred.CRED_TYPE_GENERIC)
```

gives error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\code\daily_files_uploader.py", line 11, in <module>
        credential = win32cred.CredRead(target_name, win32cred.CRED_TYPE_GENERIC)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    pywintypes.error: (1168, 'CredRead', 'Element not found.')
```

But the credential is indeed present.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that the `target_name ` you have declared in the script exactly matches the name of the credential you're trying to retrieve from the Windows Credential Manager, I see something missing between `cache` and `com`.
Also, Ensure that your script is running with the necessary permissions to access the Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: I just stripped it to hide the URL. I am using the correct name in the script though.

Comment: Everything else seems fine, did you ensure you have the proper permissions? I mean you can run the script as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this yesterday.  My issue was that I used the top option in the Windows Credential manager to store my creds.  That option is a "Windows Credential".  You need to use the generic credential category at the bottom of the list when adding.